# Jackcess columns out of order?

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jackcess

I have an application which downloads financial data from the YQL table yahoo.finance.quotes in an xml format, and then writes this data to an MS Access database.  I am using Jackcess to interact with the database but I am having a strange issue with adding rows.

When I call *.addRow()* all of the fields are written to the file correctly except a few which are switched. Here's an example of an xml file I would download and use (with JAXB)...

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2013-08-01T18:03:53Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
  <results>
    <quote>
      <BookValue>236.698</BookValue>
      <EarningsShare>34.565</EarningsShare>
      <EPSEstimateCurrentYear>43.54</EPSEstimateCurrentYear>
      <EPSEstimateNextYear>51.34</EPSEstimateNextYear>
      <EPSEstimateNextQuarter>11.82</EPSEstimateNextQuarter>
      <DaysLow>895.00</DaysLow>
      <DaysHigh>903.07</DaysHigh>
      <YearLow>623.41</YearLow>
      <YearHigh>928.00</YearHigh>
      <LastTradePriceOnly>901.83</LastTradePriceOnly>
      <FiftydayMovingAverage>893.586</FiftydayMovingAverage>
      <TwoHundreddayMovingAverage>856.999</TwoHundreddayMovingAverage>
      <Open>895.67</Open>
      <PreviousClose>887.75</PreviousClose>
      <PriceSales>5.30</PriceSales>
      <PriceBook>3.75</PriceBook>
      <PERatio>25.68</PERatio>
      <PEGRatio>1.41</PEGRatio>
      <PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear>20.39</PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear>
      <PriceEPSEstimateNextYear>17.29</PriceEPSEstimateNextYear>
      <ShortRatio>1.90</ShortRatio>
      <OneyrTargetPrice>985.32</OneyrTargetPrice>
      <Volume>1460983</Volume>
      <Ask>901.90</Ask>
      <AverageDailyVolume>2330360</AverageDailyVolume>
      <Bid>901.54</Bid>
    </quote>
  </results>
</query>
<!--  total: 222  -->
<!--  engine4.yql.ne1.yahoo.com  -->
```

And here's an xml export of the resulting access database...

```
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2013-08-01T13:28:55">
  <GOOG>
    <ID>1375380249345</ID>
    <BOOK_VALUE>901.9</BOOK_VALUE>
    <EARNINGS_SHARE>3.75</EARNINGS_SHARE>
    <EPS_ESTIMATE_CURRENT_YEAR>34.565</EPS_ESTIMATE_CURRENT_YEAR>
    <ESP_ESTIMATE_NEXT_YEAR>43.54</ESP_ESTIMATE_NEXT_YEAR>
    <EPS_ESTIMATE_NEXT_QUARTER>51.34</EPS_ESTIMATE_NEXT_QUARTER>
    <DAYS_LOW>11.82</DAYS_LOW>
    <DAYS_HIGH>895</DAYS_HIGH>
    <YEAR_LOW>903.07</YEAR_LOW>
    <YEAR_HIGH>623.41</YEAR_HIGH>
    <LAST_TRADE_PRICE_ONLY>1.9</LAST_TRADE_PRICE_ONLY> <!-- Offending column -->
    <FIFTYDAY_MOVING_AVERAGE>928</FIFTYDAY_MOVING_AVERAGE>
    <TWO_HUNDREDDAY_MOVING_AVERAGE>901.83</TWO_HUNDREDDAY_MOVING_AVERAGE>
    <OPEN>893.586</OPEN>
    <PRICE_SALES>856.999</PRICE_SALES>
    <PRICE_BOOK>895.67</PRICE_BOOK>
    <PE_RATIO>5.3</PE_RATIO>
    <PEG_RATIO>3.75</PEG_RATIO>
    <PRICE_EPSESTIMATE_CURRENT_YEAR>25.68</PRICE_EPSESTIMATE_CURRENT_YEAR>
    <PRICE_EPS_ESTIMATE_NEXT_YEAR>1.41</PRICE_EPS_ESTIMATE_NEXT_YEAR>
    <ONEYR_TARGET_PRICE>985.32</ONEYR_TARGET_PRICE>
    <SHORT_RATIO>1460983</SHORT_RATIO> <!-- Offending column -->
    <VOLUME>2330360</VOLUME> <!-- Offending column -->
    <ASK>20.39</ASK>
    <AVERAGE_DAILY_VOLUME>901</AVERAGE_DAILY_VOLUME> <!-- Offending column -->
    <BID>17.29</BID>
  </GOOG>
</dataroot>
```

Here's my code to add the values from the xml to the database if it helps...

```
public synchronized void storeData(Query query) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    long idL = System.currentTimeMillis();
    BigDecimal id = new BigDecimal(idL);
    double bookValue = query.results.quote.getPriceBook();
    double earningsShare = query.results.quote.getEarningsShare();
    double epsEstimateCurrentYear = query.results.quote.getEPSEstimateCurrentYear();
    double epsEstimateNextYear = query.results.quote.getEPSEstimateNextYear();
    double epsEstimateNextQuarter = query.results.quote.getEPSEstimateNextQuarter();
    double daysLow = query.results.quote.getDaysLow();
    double daysHigh = query.results.quote.getDaysHigh();
    double yearLow = query.results.quote.getYearLow();
    double yearHigh = query.results.quote.getYearHigh();
    double lastTradePriceOnly = query.results.quote.getLastTradePriceOnly();
    double fiftydayMovingAverage = query.results.quote.getFiftydayMovingAverage();
    double twoHundreddayMovingAverage = query.results.quote.getTwoHundreddayMovingAverage();
    double open = query.results.quote.getOpen();
    double priceSales = query.results.quote.getPriceSales();
    double priceBook = query.results.quote.getPriceBook();
    double peRatio = query.results.quote.getPERatio();
    double pegRatio = query.results.quote.getPEGRatio();
    double priceEPSEstimateCurrentYear = query.results.quote.getPriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear();
    double priceEPSEstimateNextYear = query.results.quote.getPriceEPSEstimateNextYear();
    double shortRatio = query.results.quote.getShortRatio();
    double oneyrTargetPrice = query.results.quote.getOneyrTargetPrice();
    int volume = query.results.quote.getVolume();
    double ask = query.results.quote.getAsk();
    int averageDailyVolume = query.results.quote.getAverageDailyVolume();
    double bid = query.results.quote.getBid();
    dBTable.addRow(id, bookValue, earningsShare, epsEstimateCurrentYear, epsEstimateNextYear, epsEstimateNextQuarter, daysLow, daysHigh,
        yearLow, yearHigh, close, fiftydayMovingAverage, twoHundreddayMovingAverage, open, priceSales, priceBook,
            peRatio, pegRatio, priceEPSEstimateCurrentYear, priceEPSEstimateNextYear, shortRatio, oneyrTargetPrice, volume, ask, averageDailyVolume, bid);
}
```

As you can see the *Last trade price only, Short ratio, Volume* and *Average daily volume* are mixed around.

Could anyone tell me why this is and how to correct it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least part of your problem appears to be that the `addRow()` method in Jackcess requires the values to be provided "*in the order of the Columns of the Table*", (emphasis theirs, ref: the "Adding a Row" section [here](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/cookbook.html#Adding_a_Row)). Your `addRow()` call specifies

```
... shortRatio, oneyrTargetPrice, volume ...
```

but the XML dump of the Access table suggests that the column order is

```
<ONEYR_TARGET_PRICE>985.32</ONEYR_TARGET_PRICE>
<SHORT_RATIO>1460983</SHORT_RATIO> <!-- Offending column -->
<VOLUME>2330360</VOLUME> <!-- Offending column -->
```

You may also want to double-check the variable types against the column types to make sure that they match as well.